# Can I use a spell after I complete all the tasks?

Tags: elder-sign

Can I use a spell to heal all my stamina after I complete the final task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you can use spells at the end of an adventure after completing all tasks.**  This includes using Dice Lock spells, allowing you to lock unused dice that may be useful for other players on their turn, such as the red die on a wildcard result.